# postgreql two dimensional array literal not recognized

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql, execute

```
select pg_typeof('{{"a","b",NULL},{"c","d",NULL},{"e","f",NULL}}'::varchar[][]);
```

and the output is

```
      pg_typeof      
---------------------
 character varying[]
```

similiarly,

```
select pg_typeof(array[array['a','b',NULL],array['c','d',NULL],array['e','f',NULL]]);
```

will output

```
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 text[]
```

Why it's recognized as one dimensional array?

Comment: This is normal. Arrays of all dimensions (and cardinalities) have the same type. You can use `array_dims` to access the current dimensions of a particular array value.

Comment: Why is that? The implementation of multi-dimension-arrays in postgres looks so weird to me